# Service reference config

Tags: c#, web-services, class

I have standard class library infrastructure assembly which i reference in my main application.
The infrastructure assembly uses a webservice internally and exposes functionality to my main application.

To get it to work i need to add a reference in my main app to the webservice otherwise i get a Endpointexeption. If i add it everything works fine. It seems to me that the infrastructure dll reads information in the main applications app.config so the entry has to be there. But it seems strange that i cant expose the web service throug an external dll as the main application does not call the webservie directly. Whats even stranger is that the webservice ignores the main applications security mode and reads it from the external dll's app.config.

If im correct in my assumptions, how do i expose a webservice in an external dll withot the main app knowing about the webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your class library project when you add the service reference you have to make sure the generated proxy is Internal.

for more info:

[C#, WCF, Hide web service through dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526731/c-wcf-hide-web-service-through-dll)

This will hide the WCF interface to the client.

if you don't want that the client that uses your class library project needs to add the WCF configuration key in its app/web.config your library has to configure the EndPoint/address/binding in the code (hard coded)  but I won't recommend you to go down this road as if something changes on the WCF side your class library won't work anymore

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i did what you recommened and added a class in infrastructure that exposes webservice methods, but still got same problem. If i add info in main application app.config then it works

Comment: I have accepted your point not to configure endpoint/binding internally and added necessary information in main app.config. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the service reference to your main app, but you must copy the relevant configurations to the main app.config